# MySQL Query to join tables based on columns

Tags: php, mysql

Just looking for some help with this, i'm sure it is incredibly simple but after so many hours doing other areas of my site, i'm going a bit batty.

I just have a gaming competition whereby I have a table called 'leaders' that has only these columns:

fk_memberid  |  points_total

Quite simple. Then I have this query I found elsewhere on this forum to just get the rankings of each member.

```
    SELECT 
    fk_memberid, 
    points_total, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM leaders WHERE points_total>x.points_total) AS rank_upper, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leaders WHERE points_total>=x.points_total) AS rank_lower 
FROM 
    `leaders` x
```

My question is, how do I link the fk_memberid column to another table called "members" to the corresponding column "k_memberid"? I do this all the time of course but for some reason i'm struggling in this case due to the different type of query i'm familiar with above.

Sorry for the likely incredibly easy answer. Appreciate the help.

Comment: select 'your_required_columns' from leaders l left join members m on m.k_memberid = l.fk_member_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick example here:

```
SELECT l.fk_memberid, l.points_total, m.first_name FROM leaders l 
left join member m
on m.k_member_id=l.fk_member_id
WHERE ...
```

This will give you back a table with 3 columns, 2 from leader table and "first_name" (assuming it exists) from member table

Comment: That's what i'm after but how (where) does it fit within the query I provided? The nested selects and 'leaders x' parts confuse me I suppose.

Comment: Actually I got it based on this answer: "SELECT x.fk_memberid, x.points_total, m.mem_fname, m.mem_surname, (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM leaders WHERE points_total>x.points_total) AS rank_upper, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leader WHERE points_total>=x.points_total) AS rank_lower FROM `leaders` x left join members m on x.fk_memberid=m.k_memberid ORDER BY points_total DESC"

Comment: I can't exactly understand which data you need. Please post an a example of the data you have in both tables and tell us what you want to extract

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing 
         SELECT * FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2 
         WHERE T1.column_name = T2.column_name AND Another_comditio(if you want);
may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM leaders
 LEFT JOIN members ON members.k_memberid = leaders.fk_memberid